# Changing ownership of Google Documents

Tags: google-drive, account-management, google-account, google-docs

The rules around transferring ownership of a Google Document to another user appear to have [recently changed](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/g3TUIV9NJr4/WPtqvkqFqBUJ), so I'd like some clear answers around what is and isn't possible.

My testing indicates that:

- It is not possible to transfer ownership of a Google Document from one Gmail account to another.
- It is possible to transfer ownership of a Google Document from one Google Apps account to another in the same domain.
- It is not possible to transfer ownership of a Google Document from a non-Gmail Google account to a Gmail Google account.
- It is (sometimes) possible to transfer ownership of a Google Document from a Gmail Google Account to a non-Gmail Google Account (not a Google Apps account).

This last finding confuses me a lot and is the reason I suspect I don't understand what's going on here, thus prompting my question!

I strongly suggest users test their answers before replying to this question. A lot of the online documentation (both Google and third party) appears to be out of date, non-specific or inaccurate. That's another reason I'm asking here...

Note that I am asking about changing ownership using the web interface. I am aware there are workarounds, such as downloading and reuploading documents, making copies, using third-party tools like [Migrator](https://www.migrationapp.com/about) etc. These are all interesting, but not the focus of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Pertaining to your question, I shall answer according to the sequence of points given above:

- Correct. It is not possible to transfer ownership of the document. You can share the document using the first account and get the second account to create a copy of it on Google Drive and delete the original file.
- Correct. There is a feature in the Google Apps Domain panel that allows domain administrators to easily copy everything in the Google Drive of one account to another. The only limitation is that it *must* be within the same domain.
- Correct. As per point #1, it is already not possible to transfer ownership of documents between accounts, whether it is an @gmail.com or not account.
- Incorrect. It is not possible to even transfer ownership from one account to another. However, you can do the same thing as pointed out in point #1 by sharing the document and creating a copy using the second account.

If you would like to transfer ownership of documents entirely using the web interface, I would strongly suggest that you either use third-party tools, or share everything in the Google Drive of the original account with the destination account, and create a copy of everything shared just within Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm interested that your tests showed different results for the fourth situation from mine. Yesterday I transferred ownership several times from a Gmail account to a non-Gmail account. Can you give more details about how you tested this?

Comment: Hi, I would actually be even more interested if you share with us how you managed to transfer ownership of your documents from a Gmail account to a non-Gmail account. I never heard of a direct way of making this possible.

Comment: Just the usual method. I shared the document with a non-Gmail Google account  (yahoo.com) and then changed that account to 'Is Owner'. As I wrote in my question, it's strange that it works, because I don't think it was like that before.
Anyway, how did you test it?

Comment: Oh, so you are referring to an account that isn't really using Google Drive. I was trying to refer to transferring of ownership from a Google Account to a Google Apps account. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Ah, I see how we got confused. Apologies for the lack of clarity in my question - I've edited it. Part of the problem is that there are (at least) three types of accounts here: (1) Gmail accounts (2) Google Apps for Domains accounts (3) Google Accounts with non-Gmail, non Google Apps for Domains addresses. I'm not sure what a good way to refer to (3) is!

Comment: By the way, I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'not really using Google Drive'. I can sign up for a Google Account with, for example, a @yahoo.com email address. As far as I know, I can then use Google Drive with that Google Account just as well as if I was using a Gmail-based Gmail account. Am I mistaken?